# EventBus Unable to start activity in java android

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm building a treatment in an Android app and I want to send an EventBus from my Service class to my Activity.

So I put Event bus in onCreate() methode :

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And I have this function that call the function showNFCAction that start the activity:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN, priority = 0)
public void onEventMainThread(NoSubscriberEvent event)
{
   Logger.d("No suscriber !");
   Intent intent = ((Intent) event.originalEvent);
      app.showNFCAction(intent);


}
```

The function showNFCAction:

```
showNFCAction(Intent intent)  {
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

But the new activity doesn't start.

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android. Is your UI in the foreground at the time you are trying to start the `ACTION_SETTINGS` activity?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to start it on an android 9th version, for the 2nd quetion : yes

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez the ACTION_SETTINGS activity doesn't start when I try to start it using nfc tag